# How to migrate JSP page to JSF 2.0 which can be supported by richfaces 4

Tags: jsp

I am migrating my JBOSS 5 project built on JSF 1.2 to Wildfly 13, which supports richfaces 4 and above. Where do I need to make the change so that the below error coming could resolve while I change my lib jars to richfaces 4.5.17?

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://richfaces.org/a4j"
>
> Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://richfaces.org/rich"

My project has both-EJB and Web module which is developed in JBOSS 5 and deployed as a EAR file. I have tried replacing my old richfaces JARS by new richfaces 4 Jars which  are supported by wildfly 13.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%-- <%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%> --%>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
 </html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
<!-- Version 1.1 change Starts -->
<%@ taglib prefix="a4j"  uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j"%>
```

I expect that I should not change my code so that the layout of my JSP page doesn't change, however I am getting the below errors:

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://richfaces.org/a4j"
>
> Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://richfaces.org/rich"

Comment: Jsf 1.2 or JSF 2.0? what is the correct version you want to upgrade your project? if you want to migrate your JSP to JSF **2.0** I think it is more difficult because JSF 2.0 is Facelet and all page JSF they go through a FacesContext. But this is only my experience I don't know exactly if is possible

Comment: Thanks @vincenzopalazzo i just want my project to be migrated to wildfly 13 build with openJDK 11, with whatever best solution without touching the code. Please help

Comment: Do you use pure JSP? or any framework? and now I have a question if you want only migrate into another container, you have an exception with your code without change?

Comment: Yes @vincenzopalazzo , My webpage is JSP and my project is a java one. And yes I am getting the below mentioned error of :
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://richfaces.org/a4j"

Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://richfaces.org/rich". While importing the richfaces 4 libs.